# If interpoles are used in DC motors and reduced the entire armature flux then how is torque induced in the motor?

Tags: motor

If interpoles are used in DC motors and reduced the entire armature flux then how is torque induced in the motor?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

> If interpoles are used in DC Motors and reduced the entire armature flux then how is torque induced in the motor?

Interpoles only reduce/alter flux around where the commutator/brushes are located to reduce sparks and arcs wearing down the brushes. They don't significantly alter the total flux at all. The idea behind the interpole is that the voltage on successive commutation plates is reduced (by the field in the interpole) hence the carbon brush isn't acting as a short between the commutation plates.